# what is the need of Servlet.jar in eclipseIDE when we create a servlet in Dynamic Web Project using Build Path option?

Tags: java, servlets, jar

I was going through java tutorials and found that after creating the servlet they have added the servlet.jar file using build path opt. But in my case servlet is still working without that external jar file.
So what is the need of that external jar file?

Answer (score 1):

It's still working fine in your case because 
Just check below

Right click on your project then go to Properties -> Targeted Runtime -> Apache tomcat

If you have selected that checkbox you no need to add servlet jar and if it's not then you need to add servlet jar in lib folder

So in your case you must have selected targeted runtime that's why even though u have not added servlet  jar file it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add because you may have **added Apache Tomcat as server run time in for your web project and Apache tomcat has servlet.jar in its lib folder so it will be there**

you can check it by going in Apache tomcat folder > lib

Answer (score 0):

You need Servlet-api.jar to compile servlets in eclipse but while deploying servlet container ( like tomcat ) will have it built in. Infact it is bad practise to include it inside your WEB-INF/LIB folder.If you configure your eclipse to use libraries from tomcat(or other servlet containers) then you might not need it manually.

Servlet-api.jar is by default provided by the container environment. So you should not put it in your WEB-INF/LIB folder when you are deploying your application. However, it is required for compiling your Servlets. In case if you are using Eclipse as your IDE, place it in your classpath using Add External JAR files option.

Ensure that you're using at least Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers (with the EE). It contains development tools to create dynamic web projects and easily integrate servletcontainers (those tools are part of Web Tools Platform, WTP). You also need to ensure that you already have a servletcontainer installed which implements at least the same Servlet API version as the servletcontainer in the production environment, for example Apache Tomcat, Oracle GlassFish, JBoss AS/WildFly, etc.

You should above all never manually copy/download/move/include the individual servletcontainer-specific libraries like servlet-api.jar, jsp-api.jar, el-api.jar, j2ee.jar, javaee.jar, etc. It would only lead to future portability, compatibility, classpath and maintainability troubles, because your webapp would not work when it's deployed to a servletcontainer of a different make/version than where those libraries are originally obtained from.

These links below will give you more information about this

[How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

[Understanding who provides servlet-api.jar, is it web-container or part of Java EE download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256768/understanding-who-provides-servlet-api-jar-is-it-web-container-or-part-of-java)

http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/JARFilesYouShouldNeverIncludeInYourWebapp