# Is HttpServlet definition (Servlet implementation) provided in Java EE or a WebContainer?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I read Servlet is a Java EE specification and that involves packages javax.servlet , javax.servlet.http.

As a part of implementing the specification, one need to provide a class that defines `Servlet` interface (in package javax.servlet). So is this job done by Java EE itself through `HttpServlet` class (in package javax.servlet.http).

So I am confused is Java EE one that created Servlet specification and also provided implementation for that specification.

Comment: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet is an abstract class , not an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet is an abstract class , not an implementation. Java EE does provide any implementation for Servlet.

Servlet containers (like Tomcat, JBoss, GlassFish etc.) also contain the servlet-api.jar else they would not be able to run your web application, and moreover they also contain the implementation of the interfaces that are part of the Servlet API ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256768/understanding-who-provides-servlet-api-jar-is-it-web-container-or-part-of-java)).

Answer (score -1):

There is no default implementation for sure, implementation of servlet is a responsibility of application developer. As already mentioned, you need to extend javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet for this purpose.

And you do not need EE container to make it work, Web container is enough.